# constexpression in derived class, clang vs rest

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Minimal example:

```
#include <cstddef>
struct B
{
    constexpr static const size_t MAX = 10;
};

struct D : B 
{
    constexpr static const size_t MAX = 20;
};

void use(const B& v)
{
    static_assert(v.MAX == 10, "");
}

template<typename X>
void use2(X&& v)
{
    static_assert(v.template MAX == 20, "");
}

int main ()
{
    D d;
    static_assert(d.MAX == 20, "");
    use(d);
    use2(d);

    return 0;
}
```

GCC   (v5.4 ... v7.3): compiles fine (any level of optimization and -Wall -Wextra -pedantic)
ICC / MSVC : compiles fine (tried with various versions on godbolt.org)

CLANG (v4 ... v6) : error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
        static_assert(v.MAX == 10, "");

EDIT (rephrasing the question) :

In my opinion clang's behaviour is the least surprising one (or the more intuitive). Given it's the only compiler failing to compile the above code, I'd like to understand which of the 2 behaviours is correct and why?

EDIT 2 :

Judging by this addition of a template function, gcc looks to use the declared type of the parameter and work out which constexpr member to use regardless of what's passed in.

If passing by value, clang will also assess MAX as a constant expression. In this case it is obvious why v.MAX == 10 would be true for all compilers for non-templated function.

EDIT 3 (even shorter version):
Which still does not compile on clang

```
#include <cstddef>

struct B
{
     constexpr static const size_t MAX = 10;
};

void use(const B& v)
{
    static_assert(v.MAX == 10, "");
}

template<typename X>
void use2(X&& v)
{
    static_assert(v.template MAX == 10, "");
}

int main ()
{
    B v;
    static_assert(v.MAX == 10, "");
    use(v);
    use2(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which version of each compiler are you using?

Comment: Why is clang's behaviour correct? Looks like the one with a bug to me.

Comment: What makes you think clang is right? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Because of the questions asking why clang is right: `v.MAX` means "evaluate `v`, discard the result, evaluate `B::MAX`". Compilers know that "evaluate `v`, discard the result" is completely useless and optimise it to just "evaluate `B::MAX`". The "evaluate `v`" is the only thing that would make the expression non-constant though. clang keeps treating it as non-constant even after that optimisation, and although I haven't checked the standard (yet), intuitively I would agree with that, optimisations should not affect whether the expression is constant.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : tried many versions for the above compilers (gcc : 4.0 -> 7.3, clang : 4 -> 6, etc.)

Comment: I'll re-phrase the question. In my mind clang's result is the least ambiguous. Code was trimmed down to only the smallest example. Original code would for instance allocate/traverse an std::array with size v.MAX.

Comment: @aschepler If you can elaborate on why you believe [expr.const]2.9 "an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization [...]" does not render the expression non-constant, that would work as an answer to the question.

Comment: "Judging by this addition of a template function, gcc looks to use the declared type of the parameter and work out which constexpr member to use regardless of what's passed in." -- Yes. That's also what clang does. It's not like it's `virtual`. If that's what you were after, this is not going to work in any C++ compiler, sorry.

Comment: @hvd I know it's not virtual (or virtual like behaviour). Yet why is clang not using that type? My code actually was using the above constexpr in a project (with no derived classes!) until I had to compile with clang ...

Comment: @da_m_n What type is it not using? `B`? It *is* using that. That's why outside of `static_assert`, you'll find that `v.MAX == 10` exactly as with GCC. The only thing it disagrees on is on whether `v.MAX` is a constant expression. But you can just write `B::MAX` (or something involving `decltype(v)`) directly to avoid the whole problem.

Comment: @hvd Sure, there are many ways to fix the compilation failure. The question is : why does it fail to compile and is that backed by anything in the standard?

Comment: @da_m_n I already covered that in earlier comments, without enough certainty to post that as an answer, but was thrown off by your comment in which you suggested (at least that's how I read it) that you were after something completely different from what clang was actually doing.

Comment: @hvd I've rephrased the question since in the end I was not expecting clang to fail there (see edit 3). Then I assumed it might be due to passing a reference (which could have different type than declared argument, i.e. derived) and tried that as an example to see what does gcc in that case, in the hope that gcc would fail there and clang is better at foreseeing this situation. Clearly was a wrong assumption, but still can't explain clang's failure to compile edit3 example.

Comment: Why is there a `template` keyword before `MAX`?

Comment: Please don't signify edits/updates, but edit your post. posts on SO should not tell the user of their history, but be a set of clear questions with clear answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang is correct.

`v.MAX == 10` evaluates `v`, which is a reference without a preceding initialization. This is not allowed in a constant expression.

Note even if `MAX` is a static member, `v` is still evaluated during the evaluation of `v.MAX`.

You can use the class type to access `MAX` to avoid the evaluation of `v`, for example

```
void use(const B& v)
{
    static_assert(B::MAX == 10, "");
               // ^^^
}

template<typename X>
void use2(X&& v)
{
    static_assert(std::remove_reference_t<X>::MAX == 10, "");
               // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```